# Keras Functional model for CNN - why 2 conv layers?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I'm having some difficulty in interpreting the functional model layers in keras:

Does the code below mean we are doing 2 convolutions before max pooling? 
If so, why are we doing it twice and then pooling? (Code taken from Kaggle competition [using unet](https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/data-preprocessing-and-unet-segmentation-gpu/notebook))

```
c1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (inputs)
c1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c1)
p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)
```

The reason I'm confused is because the Sequential model [here](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d#file-classifier_from_little_data_script_1-py-L78) from the official Keras examples will just do a conv layer and then pool it.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does the code below mean we are doing 2 convolutions before max pooling?** Yes, it means you are doing two convolutions before pooling.

**If so, why are we doing it twice and then pooling?** Why not? This is a just a different model. The results are not going to change a whole lot and by no means it's wrong to do this. In fact, this will probably improve the accuracy of the model, since more convolutions before reducing the size of the feature maps with the pooling can lead to more interesting representations of the data.

The intuition is: before doing pooling, you have more pixels than after (and before the first pooling you even have all the original pixels). Thus, the filters will be able to slide more times along the image and perform more convolutional operations, leading to a richer representation.

The trade-off of course is computational time. That is why more modern models started stacking many more convolutional layers before the pooling layers.

Comment: Aren't the filters that we are using for the 1st and 2nd convolution, the same filter? In that case, how will it be a richer feature representation? Pardon my basic questions! I'm just getting the hang of this stuff

Comment: @nababs no, generally filters are not shared between layers

Comment: @shimao thanks! Then it make sense that we get richer representations. Can I ask though, when Makondo says "modern models started stacking many more convolutional layers before the pooling layers", does that mean the filter would be shared? If so, how would that look in code?

Comment: @nababs No, it just means there are many convolutional layers before a pooling layer. The filters are not shared